How can I calculate the breakeven date of a rental property?
I'm trying to build a spreadsheet for a house purchase in the future.
I cannot find what I want online so, I'm trying to build it myself.
It takes in my mortgage and rental income and delivers a profit/loss number and a how many years for my investment to breakeven.
I wanted this spreadsheet to be flexible to take in various rental scenarios (in good times and bad).   I even wanted to add taxes, but I'm not that smart.

However, I don't believe it is giving me the correct information.

Can you look and make a suggestion?
The spreadsheet can be found here:
Spreadsheet

spreadsheet is not available: "This item might not exist or is no longer available"

what does "break even" mean in your context?

That's one of the more complicated analyses to make. I suggest breaking it out into a few different steps:
1. Rental operation budget
Make a budget for all expense categories that are applicable to your case: Property taxes, insurance, utilities, HOA dues, legal fees (for example LLC fees), yard service, trash, snow removal, regular maintenance, saving for larger projects (new roof, new sewer etc), etc. You have to make some educated guesses here or get some quotes. This also depends a bit on how "hands on" you are: how much of the nitty gritty will you do yourself vs hiring it out.
Next you tally up the income: this is the project sum of all rents times a "load factor". Not everything will be rented out 100% of the time and you need to account for that.
Subtract the expenses from the income: that's your net profit without taxes and interest.
2. Work out a mortgage
Figure out how much money you need. That's the price of the house plus all closing costs, plus whatever initial renovations you need to do plus an initial cash cushion minus your down payment.
Get some quotes and figure the what conditions you can get and what the optimum term is. Build a mortgage spreadsheet that shows the yearly interest (which will decline year on year).
Once you no you monthly mortgage payment you can subtract the interest from the result of step 1. This will be your "net operating income/loss".
3. Make a cash flow analysis for one year
While the income will be fairly steady, expenses can be quite spiky. Things like insurance or property taxes are paid quarterly or yearly, snow removal and heating costs are high in winter, etc. So even if your rental is profitable you can still have short term underflows. Doing a rough layout will tell you what cash reserve you will need.
4. Build a master spreadsheet
Here you tie the "big picture" together. Build a spreadsheet that shows rental income, rental expenses, mortgage interest, mortgage payments, etc on a year by year basis. You do not need to carryover the supporting details, just the final numbers. You can look at your profit/loss from year to year and calculate your increased equity share in the property.
This is also a good spot work in inflation. First order assumption could be that rent, expenses and property value are all increasing at the same rate as inflation but if you have reason to believe otherwise, here is the point to adjust it. The only thing that's NOT affected by inflation is your mortgage payment. That's fixed and you will look better and better as time goes by.
5. Taxes
Taxes vary wildly from location to location, so you need something that's specific to your local tax laws. In most cases, the mortgage interest is tax deductible  but the net profit/loss is taxable income. What rate that would be taxed at depends on your specific situation.
6. Set a benchmark
In order to determine whether this is a "good" investment you can compare it to "whatever else could I do with the down payment". You can look at investing in S&P500, CDs or bond funds and see how the different risk/reward scenarios could play out over time and see if there is something you like a better.
Here it's important to work inflation into the model. One of the biggest upsides of a rental property is that both the value and income from the investment is more "inflation protected" as almost all other forms of investment.

Says it better than I did.

"whatever else could I do with the down payment" also often referred to as "opportunity cost", which could also be a useful term for the OP. (don't forget to include the right capital gain taxes in that calculation)

You have made an excellent spreadsheet. The only issue that I am seeing with what you are looking for is you are looking in the wrong place. Essentially what you are doing is a calculus principle.
You have a function for your total income and your total cost.
This is the method you are trying:
For your total revenue (we’re just going to say revenue) and your total cost:
TR(x) and C(x)
we will assume rental income of $1,000 a month and cost of $500 a month for simplicity.
x = months
R = Rent
C = Cost
TR(x) = Total Revenue function
TR(x) = Rx - Cx
TR(x) = $1,000(1) - $500(1) = $500
That would be your first month.
To find when you have all your money back that you invested, you can just increment x until you find that you have made your investment back.
You’re essentially taking that approach to finding your break even, and you are trying to adjust for more variables.
Here is a better way to do it (and the way it is done in finance):
You need to annualize all cash flows.
If it makes $1,000 a month, you multiply by 12 for $12,000 a year.
You need to divide your annualized cash flows by an annuity factor to find the present value of your cash flows.
Here are our variables and setup:
Cash Flows = Cash Flows
r = discount rate (you can use the return you would like to make in this investment)
n = years
I’m on my phone so I cannot superscript. 2 squared is written 2^2, just like in Excel.
Let’s say you want to make a 7% return (0.07).
r = 0.07
Cash Flows = $12,000 each year
n = years
Years increments linearly (1,2,3,4,5,…)
Annuity Factor = (1+r)^n
Divide your cash flows by the annuity factor.
Let’s do it for three years so you can see the method:
Cash Flow / (1+r)^n
$12,000 / (1+0.07)^1 = $11,214.95
$12,000 / (1+0.07)^2 = $10,481.26
$12,000 / (1+0.07)^3 = $9,795.57
Keep going as much as you need to. You will eventually see the outputs get very small.
Since you are taking out a mortgage, we will say do that for 30 years. Your very last cash flow will be:
$12,000 / (1+0.07)^30 = $1,576.40
Now, you have 30 years worth of cash flows that have diminished in value each year.
You have performed a “Discounted Cash Flow” analysis.
In Excel use the =SUM() function to sum them all up.
If the sum of all your discounted cash flows is less than what you will pay for the home, it is safe to say that it is not a good investment, especially if you are taking out a mortgage.
We held your cash flows constant in that example. You can adjust them like this:
Pose the question: “What percentage of my income goes to expenses?”
The answer is, “It varies”, but let’s just say it is 40%.
In another column in Excel, multiply each of those discounted cash flows by 0.4 and subtract the number you get from the discounted cash flow.
Like this:
DCF = Discounted Cash Flow
DCF - (DCF * 0.4)
Do that for each of the 30 values and calculate the sum of all of those. Is this number less than or greater than what you will pay for the home?
To adjust for taxes (on your profits) you just repeat the same process weighting for the tax rate like you did the expenses, but do it with the numbers where the expenses were taken into account.
Something to keep in mind… As your cash flow values diminish all the way down to under $2,000 for the year, your mortgage payment remains the same. Also, the interest on your mortgage is part of your costs and should be treated as such.
This is not financial or investment advice. This is purely for educational purposes.
